# what's wrong with the grant all command?

Tags: mysql

```
grant all privileges on 'bbs' to 'userone'@'localhost'  IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'user2012';
```

It shows `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual`

I want to add a user `userone` and  grant all privileges to the database `bbs`.
How to correct it?

Comment: What's the rest of the error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to include an indicator for the tables in the database you want to grant the privilege. Change the query:

`grant all privileges on bbs.* to 'userone'@'localhost'  IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'user2012';`

to grant it for all the tables in the 'bbs' database.

Answer (score 2):

Leave the `'` at the table name:

```
grant all privileges on bbs to 'userone'@'localhost'  IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'user2012';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grant all privileges on 'bbs.*' to 'userone'@'localhost' identified by ‘user2012’;
```